# c++ inline function optimize macro , some code is difficult to understand

Tags: c++, macros, inline

I am learning c++ with books & some opensource c++ code , now days some code comfused me .

source code in the .h file is below:

```
_ALWAYS_INLINE_ void postinitialize_handler(void *) {}
template <class T>
_ALWAYS_INLINE_ T *_post_initialize(T *p_obj) {
    postinitialize_handler(p_obj);
    return p_obj;
}
#define memnew(m_class) _post_initialize(new ("") m_class)
```

here is how to use this memnew macro :

```
InputMap *input_map = memnew(InputMap);
```

the AlawayInline function show me a empty :

```
void function postinitialize_handler(void *){}
```

I don't konw why the anthor wrote like this,

```
InputMap *input_map = new InputMap("")
```

is clear and functioned ,why do not wrote like that but use macro memnew ?

Thanks~

Comment: Is there a need to go deeper than "Macros are Evil"?

Comment: the source file is in https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/master/core/os/memory.h , at line 94

Comment: Just because it's clearer, doesn't mean it's always fitting. Some domains (like game engines, since you look at godot) need specific performance guarantees. Leaving allocation to the general purpose memory allocator probably wasn't up to par. And that's without even considering Alan's answer, which raises *another* excellent point.

Answer (score 1):

`postinitialize_handler` is [overloaded for `Object*`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/15b68f760149aa71368e9aa35255690fd75427e6/core/object/object.cpp#L1842):

```
void postinitialize_handler(Object *p_object) {
    p_object->_postinitialize();
}
```

Therefore every `Object` created with `memnew` will have [`_postinitialize`](https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/15b68f760149aa71368e9aa35255690fd75427e6/core/object/object.cpp#L203) called on it

Comment: Thanks ~ I will try some codes like this.